# sorting based on position in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I wanted get the output in assending order (i.e high value lines to low value lines) of a file.

## file:-

```
1|21
2|12
3|0
4|2
5|1
6|3
7|13
8|32
9|123
10|1234
```

Expected Output :-

```
10|1234
9|123
8|32
1|21
7|13
2|12
6|3
4|2
5|1
3|0
```

I tried below command but not getting expected output

cmd:- `sort -t "|" -k 2 12.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to sort numbers in reverse order.

```
sort -rn -t "|" -k 2 12.txt
```